# Building LLVM OCaml bindings on Windows under MinGW using CMake?

Tags: windows, build, mingw, ocaml, llvm

I'm trying to build the LLVM OCaml bindings under MinGW on Windows using CMake. I've tweaked a little bit with the LLVMBuild.txt in the bindings directory without luck. How do I build them?

Edit: To answer ygrek's question:

First attempt:

```
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk llvm
cd llvm/tools
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk clang
cd ../projects
svn co http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk compiler-rt
cd ..
mkdir build

cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
mingw32-make
```

I realized that `llvm/bindings/ocaml` wasn't being built. I then connected the `LLVMBuild.txt` files in many directories with the CMake build system. `llvm/bindings/LLVMBuild.txt` didn't contain any instructions to build subdirectories so I added them:

```
[common]
subdirectories = ocaml
```

`llvm/bindings/ocaml/LLVMBuild.txt` didn't have an `LLVMBuild.txt` either so I added one:

```
[component_0]
type = Group
name = OCamlBindings
parent = Bindings
```

I tried building this, but the OCaml binding weren't built. I think it's because there are no `LLVMBuild.txt` in any of the `ocaml` subdirectories. I had considered adding `LLVMBuild.txt` files to all of the `ocaml` subdirectories but realized I didn't know what their dependencies were or how to specify them.

I didn't want to pursue this aimlessly if it isn't possible or if someone had already done the work. It seems like there's a disconnect between the CMake build system & the bindings directories.

Comment: What exactly steps did you try? What did you tweak? What error did you get? Tell us more - remember, we are not telepaths here (at least not all of us).

Comment: And here I thought this was StackTelepaths. :-)

Comment: On a more serious note, ygrek, thanks for asking. Hopefully the above helps.

Answer (score 2):

Not a real answer, but still.

The note at the beginning of `llvm/bindings/Makefile.ocaml` reading

> An ocaml library is a unique project type in the context of LLVM, so rules are here rather than in Makefile.rules.

seems to suggest that building ocaml bindings with cmake is not supported..